# .Net 6 publish produces both an exe and a dll and self-contained does too much

Tags: .net-core

I'm publishing a .Net 6 application for win-x64 with many dependencies, and i notice the publish generates two files: a MyApp.exe and MyApp.dll.
From what i understand it's a choice that comes from the multi-platform nature of .Net, but in my scenario i now have two files to deploy and update instead of one.

I've tried self-contained publish, but it bundles also the dependencies and bugfix updates will have to download many MB for just the main exe change.

Is there a way to bundle together only MyApp.exe and MyApp.dll without the dependencies?

Comment: Use the —no-dependencies and —no-self-contained flags https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build

Comment: "many dependencies", it doesn't make much sense to favor, say, 8 files over 7.  You don't actually need the .exe file, it is the apphost, merely a convenience to .net programmers that are used to the way .NETFramework projects worked.  You can also execute the program with `dotnet.exe mainproject.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add PublishSingleFile true in your .csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile> 
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Or pass it in during the command line publish

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 p:PublishSingleFile=true --self-contained true
```

Comment: When I use that config I get the a whole bunch of new dlls... And the app seems to require all of those so it didnt really help.

Comment: Then your single file publish is off. You can look into that more and see what's wrong in your case specifically, but it sounds like that's what you want.

Comment: @ZachSexton your command line solution worked perfectly for me.  One minor thing is I believe you need a dash in front of the relevant argument: `-p:PublishSingleFile=true`

Answer (score -4):

You need:

```
<IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>
```

along with everything Zach Sexton has provided.